# Is there a way to make quartel run on Colab at all?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, quart

I am trying to run quart on collab but it doesnt seem to work?

This is my code (its from [here](https://github.com/pallets/quart/blob/main/docs/reference/cheatsheet.rst))

```
!pip install quart
from quart import Quart

app = Quart(__name__)

@app.route("/hello")
async def hello():
    return "Hello, World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Did you import asyncio?

Comment: Did it work for you? because when I do i get other errors.

Comment: I didn't install Quart.